# Disabling specific error messages for Javascript in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint, eslint, ecmascript-next

I'm using class properties (static and normal) and decorators in JavaScript. Is there a way to either enable other ES stages for code highlighting or disable the specific error messages for them?

VSCode tells me that I can use class properties only in TypeScript, so it seems to recognize them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can disable JavaScript build-in validation with `"javascript.validate.enable": false` in settings.json and then enable either ESLint or JSHint extensions to fine-tune errors and validations. Read more [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_how-do-i-disable-syntax-validation-when-using-nones6-constructs).

Answer (score 3):

Please note that incase your javascript is written within  tags in html, the setting is called "html.validate.scripts": false.