# Turning off misidentified "Experimental decorators" linting errors in cshtml/Razor template files (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, razor

I have a legacy system that uses Razor templating.

When I open `*.cshtml` files in VSCode, I get linting errors reported in VSCode even though it's ultimately valid JavaScript.

Here's an easy example: Whatever linter it is complains I'm using "experimental decorators". I'm not.

```
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. 
Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.`
```

It's a Razor comment, which is completely legit here:
`@* If MathJax wasn't successfully loaded from cdn1, use the second: *@`

[image: Error in VSCode on a Razor comment surrounded by @s]

I have eslint installed. I use that to lint "real" JavaScript files. That, with the VSCode eslint extension, works perfectly. And I don't mind having JavaScript linting in html, but whatever's running doesn't seem to be eslint.

I tried essentially following the instructions in the error & creating a [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) file with an ignore in it, but this did not seem to work either.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": ["**/*.cshtml"]
}
```

Perhaps I borked the glob? (I tried a few -- just `*.cshtml`, `./**/*.cshtml`).

At any rate, I have no idea what's doing this linting. I searched my settings file (in raw JSON) for javascript and js and didn't find an obvious culprit there.

What linter is this? How do I make it cshtml aware? Or how do I turn linting off for `*cshtml` (and in this way, at least, my question is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131510/how-to-lint-cshtml-files)) completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for now with a workaround/less than perfect solution...

Looks like the setting to kill it is:

```
"html.validate.scripts": false,
```

I would still prefer to have scripts validated in a Razor template-aware way.

---

##### How to edit settings directly

Add this text to settings by...

1. Typing ctrl-p (cmd-p on macOS),
2. Typing `JSON`, and
3. Selecting `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.

[image: open JSON settings in ctrl-p shown]

4. Paste the snippet into the file that was opened.

---

Note: These reported errors may have been complicated by my mapping *.cshtml to *.html for it to otherwise be treated as html:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.cshtml": "html"
  },
```

I have not yet tried removing that mapping to see if the script validation would continue.

---

##### Hat-tip

Hat-tip to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36718760/1028230), which mentioned:

> You can disable JavaScript build-in validation with "javascript.validate.enable": false in settings.json and then enable either ESLint or JSHint extensions to fine-tune errors and validations.

Just needed to edit that to its html equivalent.